# Send email using template in mandrill

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have templates in Mandrill (imported from Mailchimp).

How can I specify which template I wish to use, instead of having the HTML in my application? This way, clients and non-programmers may change e-mail content without having to touch the server.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
$mandrill = new Mandrill(Config::get('services.mandrill.secret'));
$result = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate('weclome-email', [], array(
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'some@email.com',
            'name' => 'Some Name',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'merge' => true,
    'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',
    'merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'some@email.com',
            'vars' => array(
                array(
                    'FNAME' => 'Some'
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Using the https://packagist.org/packages/mandrill/mandrill package

Comment: How to include the Mandrill package in the php code?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at Mandrill's Message API [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) and specifically the send template section [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template).

You can use Guzzle to work with those API calls.